# I accidentally sent token to the currency contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I accidentally sent token to the currency contract, is it possible to get the tokens back?
Can any expert tell me if the contract has the function?
what is the function?

Contract: 0x2881a6bd504e323f70159d032f89374222e40d22

Comment: Hello, when you ask a question, try to provide us some details, like what chain the token is deployed on. Its clear that its not on ethereum mainnet so we cant review the code without you telling us where it lives. As for your question your tokens are locked forever if the token dev didnt implement a specific function to rescue tokens sent to the contract, which isn't something standard in tokens creation.

Answer (score 1):

**You should ask the token creator.**

Generally, functions that would allow your tokens to be saved are not implemented in token contracts, which means that the tokens are lost.

I had a quick look at the contract that you posted and I did **not** see such a function.